# How does OpenBazaar differ from NXT decentralized marketplace?

Tags: nxt, openbazaar

I'm contemplating if I should use openbazaar or the nxt marketplace. both a decentralized, but I have a few questions regarding openbazaar:

- What incentive does hosting a openbazaar node give? I understand that the nxt marketplace is built into the coin's blockchain so there's the incentive of mining coins while it also hosts the marketplace.
- How does openbazaar / nxt marketplace handle fees? Or is there any fees at all? There has to be some sort of fee I'd imagine or else there would be alot of spam.
- Can you upload images/pics to openbazaar/nxt ? How do they handle the bloat?
- How does user ratings work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NXT Marketplace is for digital goods. If you want to sell physical goods, you should look at the **NXT FreeMarket**, which also lives on the NXT blockchain. You can read about it here:

http://www.nxtfreemarket.com/

Comment: do you have a chart comparison with openbazaar vs freemarket? also why can't one just sell their physical goods on the nxt digital goods store?